# PHP OOP connection mysql doesn't work after initiating object

Tags: php, mysql

In oop php, i created constructor mysql connection (i know it will be deprecated and you sugest to use PDO and so on), but i'm ran into the problem. The connection is made, verything is going ok. But insertion can't be done don't know why, the code runs till the end. It seems that object doesn't take the connection, but it can't be. PHP 5.4.3 i use. The code is below:

```
Table (Coach):
Coach_id INT (AutoIncrement)
Coach_name char(30)
Coach_nationality char(30)


class League 
{
    public $con;

    public function MySQLCon()
    {
    $this->con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or mysql_error($this->con);
    mysql_select_db("basket",$this->con) or mysql_error($this->con);
    return $this->con;
    }

    public $coach,$coachNationality;

    public function NewCoach($coach,$coachNationality)
    {

        $this->coach = $coach;
        $this->coachNationality = $coachNationality;

        $Query = "insert into Coach_name (Coach_name,Coach_nationality) VALUES ('".$this->coach."','".$this->coachNationality."')";

        //this query doesn't do anything but prints yes
        mysql_query($Query,$this->con) or mysql_error($this->con);
        echo "yes";

    }
}

//no data about mike Brown in database, database engine InnoDB
$LG = new League;
$LG->MySQLCon();
$LG->NewCoach("Mike Brown","USA");
```

Comment: You cannot use a return value from a constructor... Also you are using php4 and php5 style property declarations. Also your query is wrong. That's just at first glance probably there is more wrong with your code.

Comment: Well didn't understood correctly your response, ok i edited my code as it should be. Still no insertion. As i understand php4 and php5 style property declartions you meant about var $con and public $coach. that i used here wrong yes ?

Comment: Show our updated code

Comment: Code edited as @Luceos showed but still no insertion into database.

Comment: if you do `echo $Query;` after `$Query = "...` and copy and paste the query into phpmyadmin, does it work?

Comment: All your calls to `mysql_error` should be inside `die`: Example: $this->con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error($this->con));

Comment: Thanks for answer, yeah that doesn't matter in my case, am wondeering, if these problems occurs only in OOP with mysql_* class, in you practices do you had these type of problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off start using error messages:

```
class League 
{
    var $con;

    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("No connection: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("basket",$this->con) or die("Database could not be selected: " . mysql_error($this->con));
    }

    public $coach,$coachNationality;

    public function NewCoach($coach,$coachNationality)
    {

        $this->coach = $coach;
        $this->coachNationality = $coachNationality;

        $Query = "insert into Coach_name (Coach_name,Coach_nationality) VALUES ('".$this->coach."','".$this->coachNationality."')";

        //this query doesn't do anything but prints yes
        mysql_query($Query,$this->con) or die(mysql_error($this->con));
        return true;    
    }
}

//no data about mike Brown in database, database engine InnoDB
$LG = new League;
if( $LG->NewCoach("Mike Brown","USA") ) echo "inserted, method NewCoach returned true";
```

After having edited your code;

1. the only parameter mysql_error will receive is the connection, not a string.
2. string in inserts and selects need to be surrounded by quotes '' or "".
3. the second parameter of mysql_query should be the connection
4. start using PDO or mysqli instead of mysql as it will be removed from PHP in a future release and already is considered back practice and obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My code edited like you shown, but still no insertion in database ...

Comment: And no errors? Did you enable error_reporting at all? Does the page load in a 500? Did you check the log files?

Comment: No errors ... Yes enabled:
error_reporting("E_ALL");
ini_set('dispaly_errors', true);

Comment: My table Coach looks like this.  
    Coach_id INT (AutoIncrement)
    Coach_name char(30)
    Coach_nationality char(30)
But when i try insert throug phpmyadmin everything is wen't ok...

Comment: and the echo does not show either?! I think it's weird  you're not receiving errors nor a success message..

Comment: After reinstall everything wen't ok, don't know what happend. Now this post out of sense..

Answer (score 0):

your query is wrong, you need to use single quotes for the strings:

```
"insert into Coach_name (Coach_name,Coach_nationality) VALUES ('".$this->coach."','".$coachNationality."')";
```

even better would be to make sure single qoutes in the string are escaped, like this:

```
... VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($this->coach)."', ..
```

but your code is so weird, there might be more errors

Comment: Still doesn't work. Don't know why. Replaced the query still no data in DB. And why you saying the code is so weird ? I'm doing project, but querys still not working.

Comment: look at peehaa's comment to see why your code is weird (there is even more)